# Android HTTPS exception Connection reset by peer

Tags: android, https, connection

I'm working on an application which is downloading data from a web server.It seems to download data without any problems in the beginning, but a few days ago I start receiving this kind of exceptions : `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x7a6588: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer` and I'm not sure what cause that problem and how can I fix that. Here is the whole `LogCat` message :

```
12-12 11:43:27.950: W/System.err(22010): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x7a6588: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
12-12 11:43:27.960: W/System.err(22010):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
12-12 11:43:27.960: W/System.err(22010):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:788)
12-12 11:43:27.960: W/System.err(22010):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:50)
12-12 11:43:27.960: W/System.err(22010):    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:157)
12-12 11:43:27.960: W/System.err(22010):    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:225)
12-12 11:43:27.960: W/System.err(22010):    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:178)
12-12 11:43:27.960: W/System.err(22010):    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(GZIPInputStream.java:174)
12-12 11:43:27.960: W/System.err(22010):    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:319)
12-12 11:43:27.970: W/System.err(22010):    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
12-12 11:43:27.970: W/System.err(22010):    at com.stampii.stampii.synchronization.Synchronization.UseHttpsConnection(Synchronization.java:1367)
12-12 11:43:27.970: W/System.err(22010):    at com.stampii.stampii.synchronization.Synchronization$ActivateCollection.doInBackground(Synchronization.java:613)
12-12 11:43:27.970: W/System.err(22010):    at com.stampii.stampii.synchronization.Synchronization$ActivateCollection.doInBackground(Synchronization.java:1)
12-12 11:43:27.970: W/System.err(22010):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-12 11:43:27.970: W/System.err(22010):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
12-12 11:43:27.970: W/System.err(22010):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
12-12 11:43:27.970: W/System.err(22010):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
12-12 11:43:27.970: W/System.err(22010):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
12-12 11:43:27.970: W/System.err(22010):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
```

This is what I got on my `UseHttpsConnection` method :

```
    public void UseHttpsConnection(String url, String charset, String query) {

    try {
        final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted( final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType ) {
            }
            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted( final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType ) {
            }
            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        } };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance( "TLS" );
        sslContext.init( null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom() );
        // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
        final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

        if (url.startsWith("https://")) {
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier(){
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }});
        }

        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setSSLSocketFactory( sslSocketFactory );
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */ );
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Charset", charset);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + charset);
        OutputStream output = null;
        try {
            output = connection.getOutputStream();
            output.write(query.getBytes(charset));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            showError2("Check your network settings!");

        } finally {
            if (output != null)
                try {
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {
                    logOrIgnore.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        int status = ((HttpsURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode();
        Log.d("", "Status : " + status);

        for (Entry<String, List<String>> header : connection
                .getHeaderFields().entrySet()) {
            Log.d("Headers","Headers : " + header.getKey() + "="+ header.getValue());
        }

        InputStream response = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

        int bytesRead = -1;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[30 * 1024];
        while ((bytesRead = response.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            byte[] buffer2 = new byte[bytesRead];
            System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, buffer2, 0, bytesRead);
            handleDataFromSync(buffer2);
        }
        connection.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        showError2("Synchronization failed!Please try again.");

    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        showError2("Error occured.Please try again.");

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        showError2("Error occured.Please try again.");
    }
}
```

And here is my AsyncTask which I'm using to connect and download the data :

```
    public class DeactivateCollection extends AsyncTask <Context, Integer, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Context... arrContext) {
        try {
            String charset = "UTF-8";
            hash = getAuthHash();
            SharedPreferences lastUser = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Synchronization.this);
            int userId = lastUser.getInt("lastUser", 1);

            systemDbHelper = new SystemDatabaseHelper(Synchronization.this, null, 1);
            systemDbHelper.initialize(Synchronization.this);
            String sql = "SELECT dbTimestamp FROM users WHERE objectId=" + userId;
            Cursor cursor = systemDbHelper.executeSQLQuery(sql);
            if (cursor.getCount() < 0) {
                cursor.close();
            } else if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                timeStamp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("dbTimestamp"));
                Log.d("", "timeStamp : " + timeStamp);
            }

            String query = String.format("debug_data=%s&"
                    + "client_auth_hash=%s&" + "timestamp=%s&"
                    + "deactivate_collections=%s&" + "client_api_ver=%s&"
                    + "set_locale=%s&" + "device_os_type=%s&"
                    + "device_sync_type=%s&"
                    + "device_identification_string=%s&"
                    + "device_identificator=%s&" + "device_resolution=%s",
                    URLEncoder.encode("1", charset),
                    URLEncoder.encode(hash, charset),
                    URLEncoder.encode(timeStamp, charset),
                    URLEncoder.encode(Integer.toString(deac), charset),
                    URLEncoder.encode(clientApiVersion, charset),
                    URLEncoder.encode(locale, charset),
                    URLEncoder.encode(version, charset),
                    URLEncoder.encode("14", charset),
                    URLEncoder.encode(version, charset),
                    URLEncoder.encode(deviceId, charset),
                    URLEncoder.encode(resolution, charset));

            Log.e("","hash : "+hash);
            Log.e("","deactivate : "+Integer.toString(deac));

            SharedPreferences useSSLConnection = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Synchronization.this);
            boolean useSSl = useSSLConnection.getBoolean("UseSSl", true);
            if (useSSl) {
                UseHttpsConnection(url, charset, query);
            } else {
                UseHttpConnection(url, charset, query);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        Log.d("","ON PROGRESS UPDATE");

    }
    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        Log.d("","ON CANCELLED");

    } 
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        Log.d("","ON PRE EXECUTE");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        Log.d("","ON POST EXECUTE");

    }
  }
```

**So anyone have an idea how to handle that Exception so I can download the whole data without any exceptions. Or how can I fix that if it's impossible.**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually there are two options that you can do in this situation.
You can catch that exception while downloading data over internet and create a function which will start the connection again from where it stops. So you have to find a way to save your progress while downloading the data,because if you're downloading big size of data it's not a good idea to start the process again.

Another thing that you can do is to create a dialog, which will inform the user that there is error while synchronizing and let him to choose if he want to retry the operation or cancel it.If user select Retry option I think it will be a better option to start the connection again from the where it stops again. So you have to save your progress in both ways. I think that's more user friendly.