# Trace WCF REST service errors

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, iis-7

This question came up from what I see on a clients side: [Intermittent Connection Reset by Peer errors in Android connecting to .NET REST endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021551/intermittent-connection-reset-by-peer-errors-in-android-connecting-to-net-rest)

Simply put, I suspect that my WCF service for some reason intermittenly reject clients. I wonder if there is any way to log those rejections? I'm not even sure if that happens on WCF level, maybe it happens in IIS itself before routed to WCF?

I want to know how to log any errors for requests coming to my WCF endpoint. Inside WCF there is no issues, I log any kind of exceptions thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see on this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx
using system.diagnostics section of config you can configure your service to trace all action executed to complete an operation. 
This parameter: initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
is the file location where trace information will be saved.

Comment: Any way to do same programmatically so I can log errors in my own store?

Comment: You can add your custom Behavior before and after service operation execution. WCF provide a strong Pipeline where you can implement and add your custom code to handle specific situations. This is a good article to understand this mechanism: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx