# Connection reset by peer Exception in Soap Webservice calling

Tags: android

I am calling Soap web service. It works proper but some times I am getting connection reset by peer exception.

This is my code of web service calling

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Looper.prepare();
                    String response = "";
                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelope.dotNet = true;
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(serverRequestParams.getSoapObject());

                    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(serverRequestParams.getUrl(),90000);
                    httpTransport.debug = true;
                    try {

                        HttpParams my_httpParams = new BasicHttpParams(); 
                        final String proxyHost = android.net.Proxy.getDefaultHost();
                        final int proxyPort = android.net.Proxy.getDefaultPort();
                        if(proxyPort != -1)
                        {
                            my_httpParams.setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort));            
                        }

                        httpTransport.call(serverRequestParams.getSoapAction(), envelope);
                        Object data = envelope.getResponse();
                        if (data instanceof SoapObject) {
                            SoapObject data2 = (SoapObject) data;
                            response = data2.toString();
                        } else if (data instanceof SoapPrimitive) {
                            SoapPrimitive data3 = (SoapPrimitive) data;
                            response = data3.toString();
                        } else if (data != null) {
                            response = data.toString();
                        } else if (data == null) {
                            response = "nodata";
                        }
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.print("Exception:"+e);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out following links may be one of them solves your problem

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207394/getting-socketexception-connection-reset-by-peer-in-android)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021551/intermittent-connection-reset-by-peer-errors-in-android-connecting-to-net-rest)

[link3](http://www.coderanch.com/t/222395/Web-Services/java/Connection-reset-peer-socket-write)

These links consist of some solution at client side and some on server side and also they provide information why its happening.

Let me know if this helps you.