# connection reset by peer calling soap webservice

Tags: java, web-services, sockets, networking, soap

Currently trying to invoke a web service, however i am getting a connection reset/connection reset by peer, below is the stack trace:

```
WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 81
WRITE: SSLv2 client hello message, length = 110
waiting for close_notify or alert: state 1
Exception while waiting for close java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: socket write error: Connection reset by peer.
called closeSocket()
called close()
called closeInternal(true)
called close()
called closeInternal(true)
called close()
called closeInternal(true)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650345/connection-reset-by-peer-exception-in-soap-webservice-calling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an SSL issue, as per the trace, there was only a Client Hello, but no Server Hello Response, (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html) after import of server public key to client keystore it is now working