# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted Connection reset by peer while calling webservice Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, ssl, https

I am calling **https webservice** and its works fine before, but now when i am trying to call it its give me following errors.

**Log Errors :**

```
12-23 06:28:11.969: W/System.err(3014): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x1cc160: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
12-23 06:28:11.979: W/System.err(3014):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
12-23 06:28:11.979: W/System.err(3014):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:474)
12-23 06:28:11.979: W/System.err(3014):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.<init>(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:750)
12-23 06:28:11.979: W/System.err(3014):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:692)
12-23 06:28:11.979: W/System.err(3014):     at crittercism.android.aa.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
12-23 06:28:11.979: W/System.err(3014):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.<init>(SocketInputBuffer.java:93)
12-23 06:28:11.979: W/System.err(3014):     at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.createSessionInputBuffer(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:83)
12-23 06:28:11.979: W/System.err(3014):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.createSessionInputBuffer(DefaultClientConnection.java:170)
12-23 06:28:11.979: W/System.err(3014):     at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.bind(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:106)
12-23 06:28:11.979: W/System.err(3014):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.openCompleted(DefaultClientConnection.java:129)
12-23 06:28:11.979: W/System.err(3014):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:171)
12-23 06:28:11.989: W/System.err(3014):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
12-23 06:28:11.989: W/System.err(3014):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
12-23 06:28:11.989: W/System.err(3014):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
12-23 06:28:11.989: W/System.err(3014):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
12-23 06:28:11.989: W/System.err(3014):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
12-23 06:28:11.989: W/System.err(3014):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
```

I am using following code for calling https webservice.

```
public static void trustAllHosts() {

        X509TrustManager easyTrustManager = new X509TrustManager() {

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
                // Oh, I am easy!
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
                // Oh, I am easy!
            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

        };

        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { easyTrustManager };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());

            HttpsURLConnection
                    .setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
        try {
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore
                    .getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null, null);

            SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                    .getSocketFactory(), 80));
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

            ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
                    params, registry);

            return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new DefaultHttpClient();
        }
    }
```

**MySSLSocketFactory.java**

```
public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException,
            KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(truststore);

        TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        };

        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port,
            boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port,
                autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }
}
```

It is working fine before, but now it fails. There are no any changes made in server.

I already refered

1. [Android-Query - Random SSLExceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11478987/1405983)
2. [Intermittent Connection Reset by Peer errors in Android connecting to .NET REST endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021551/intermittent-connection-reset-by-peer-errors-in-android-connecting-to-net-rest)
3. [Android HTTPS exception Connection reset by peer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8502679/1405983)
4. [Why is HttpUrlConnection throwing an SSLException while on a mobile data connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12885248/1405983)

I have tested it in both wifi and mobile data. Application not works in both.

If anybody face this problem before then please help me to solve it.

Comment: @Tamilan i have already gone through this link. I already mention it in my question.

Comment: Did you get any solution ? if yes what was it??

Comment: Read this for the complete explanation and possible resolution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538640/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-read-error-ssl-0x9524b800-i-o-error-during-system?lq=1

Comment: @DreamsNeverDie Have you find a solution? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 28):

I also got the same exception. I found that it was due to **TLS 1.0 protocol** was not supported by server.

I observed that Android device, http connection fails to the server where `TLS 1.0` is not supported. I searched every where about the bug, but did not find anything related to this problem. And the problem was solved, when the `TLS 1.0 protocol` support was added to the server.You can check your server / hostname protocol support using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest.

Comment: I am getting this exception some times on some devices but on mostly devices It is working Fine. I am using Sim Data on android phone.

Comment: Note that TLS 1.0 should not be used anymore as it is deprecated and deemed insecure, and having TLS1.0 enabled will make you fail PCI compliance. https://www.comodo.com/e-commerce/ssl-certificates/tls-1-deprecation.php

Answer (score 5):

There could be 2 reasons:

Certificates could be expired at client or server end.

Solution: 
Extend expiry date of existing certificate or Exhange  new certificates.

Server port has been reset to some else port.

Solution:
I have faced this port change problem, normally due to server maintenance or patch update, sometimes port of the service get change. Ask the person who has provided you the wsdl to regenerate wsdl on their server and check the port no whether it is matching with existing wsdl at client side or not. Most probably this would be the case here.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for response. If there is any reason from this, it also fails in iphone ? Actually in iphone app its working perfectly.

Comment: Ok Sir, If you are calling same service (end point url) from iphone app, That means you can eliminate 2nd reason, your service is working fine. But each client needs to import server certificate  or trust that particular url using self signed certificate seperately.

Comment: Okey. So problem is : "Server port has been reset to some else port" ? Can you help little more or what are the possible ways to resolve it?

Comment: Are you exchanging certificate or trusting url in your android app? i don't have much idea about your implementation above. But by seeing error, it has to do something with your certificate or end point url as you said it was working perfectly fine earlier. There must be some configuration changes in server for transport protocols something like that.

Comment: In my that way an expired certificate at the client side.

Answer (score 4):

We had this same issue starting this morning and got it solved.

SSL on IIS 8

1. Every thing was working fine yesterday and last night our SSL was updated on the IIS site.
2. While checking out the site Bindings to the SSL we noticed that IIS8 has a new checkbox "Require Server Name Indication", it was not checked so we proceeded to enable it.
3. That triggered the problem.
4. Went back to IIS, disabled the checkbox.... problem solved!

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue for some Android devices. Found the solution by **IIS server settings**.

**Steps:**

1. Open IIS
2. Select the site on which you are working
3. Edit site binding
4. **Uncheck Required Server Name Identification**
5. Click OK

**Reference screenshot:**

[image]

Hope this would helps you.