# javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException while calling HttpUrlConnection.connect()

Tags: java, android, ssl, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to create place search functionality in my app using GoogleMap's api for Android. I want to fill AutoComplete TextView as user types the name of the place. But I'm getting this Excetion while calling `urlConnection.connect();` statement:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb911cd50: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:1407743E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert inappropriate fallback (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:765 0xae688edd:0x00000000)
```

Following is the code I'm using:

```
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}

private String getPlacesUrl(String qry) {
        try {
            qry = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(qry, "utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";


        // place type to be searched
        String types = "types=geocode";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = qry + "&" + types + "&" + sensor + "&" + mKey;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";


        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/" + output + "?" + parameters;

        return url;
    }
```

I've registered my apps package and SHA1 of my system in google console. The url that I'm getting after calling `getPlaceUrl()` method is of this type:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=b&types=geocode&sensor=false&key=API_KEY

Please help me fix the issue.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741405/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-ssl-handshake-aborted-connection-reset-by-peer-while. might be helpful

Comment: @shayanpourvatan here the server is GoogleMap's Server. I don't think `TLS 1.0 protocol` support is not there

Comment: What device/API level do you execute the code? The SSL/TLS protocols and ciphers depend on the used OS.

Comment: @Robert I'm executing code on Lollypop/Kitkat devices, I'm using API level 19 for compiling the source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a almost same issue.
My logcat as follows:

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: 
SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x60b486b8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert inappropriate fallback (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:744 0x5ea50d74:0x00000000)

Finally, I found a solution it's to modify httpURLConnection.setHostnameVerifier HostnameVerifier verify return value from false to true, but I don't know the root cause.
Is there any one can supply tips?

```
        httpURLConnection.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // return false;
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: you probably mean `HttpsURLConnection`