# HTTP Request Error for different android versions

Tags: java, android

I am using android volley and `android-async-http:1.4.9` library for networking in my app. First i was only using volley for a login call to server in android `version 5.0.1` and it worked fine, but when i used volley in android version below lollipop, it gave me following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x62f65e18: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
```

Then i decided to use `android-async-http:1.4.9` library but still get the same error. Anyone please help me with this because my app should work for version greater than 16.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted Connection reset by peer while calling webservice Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741405/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-ssl-handshake-aborted-connection-reset-by-peer-while)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with android-async-http:1.4.9. I switched to  android-async-http:1.4.8 and everything worked fine. apparently, they changed something in the  android-async-http library which caused a problem - the Http client component  due to Google removal of the Apache Http client (http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html). there is an issue for this error in their GitHub repo.

In the meanwhile  - I'm using version android-async-http:1.4.8.