# Appcelerator android javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer

Tags: android, ssl, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

In my app all requests are https which works without issue on the ios version however on Android I get the following errors.

```
[ERROR] TiDownloadManager: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer
[ERROR] TiDownloadManager:  at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
[ERROR] TiDownloadManager:  at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:405)
[ERROR] TiDownloadManager:  at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:146)
[ERROR] TiDownloadManager:  at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:107)
[ERROR] TiDownloadManager:  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
[ERROR] TiDownloadManager:  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
[ERROR] TiDownloadManager:  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
[ERROR] TiDownloadManager:  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
[ERROR] TiDownloadManager:  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
[ERROR] TiDownloadManager:  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
[ERROR] TiDownloadManager:  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
[ERROR] TiDownloadManager:  at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:470)
[ERROR] TiDownloadManager:  at org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiDownloadManager$DownloadJob.run(TiDownloadManager.java:135)
[ERROR] TiDownloadManager:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
[ERROR] TiDownloadManager:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
[ERROR] TiDownloadManager:  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

This happening when running on a Genymotion emulator.

Comment: Actually only seems to be a problem with images.

Comment: please look at the documentation  of security manager and how to implement http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/SSL_Certificate_Store_Support_for_HTTP_Clients and http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-property-securityManager

Comment: Maybe the same error with TLS 1.0 not supported by the server?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741405/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-ssl-handshake-aborted-connection-reset-by-peer-while