# Why does HttpsURLConnection throw an SSL Exception when connected to a WiFi Hotspot?

Tags: java, android, ssl

I am working on an Android Application that connects to a remote API for additional data. Now just the other day my home WiFi went down so I decided to use my cellular Hotspot on my other phone. Strangely this threw a weird error in my application.

```
11-09 21:25:14.400 28932-28971/nl.lukehouben.scoutdrinks W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xbe09b0: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
        at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
        at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:410)
        at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:257)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:210)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:477)
11-09 21:25:14.410 28932-28971/nl.lukehouben.scoutdrinks W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:441)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:270)
        at nl.lukehouben.scoutdrinks.LoginActivity$getNetworkResult.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:96)
        at nl.lukehouben.scoutdrinks.LoginActivity$getNetworkResult.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:69)
11-09 21:25:14.420 28932-28971/nl.lukehouben.scoutdrinks W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-09 21:25:14.430 28932-28971/nl.lukehouben.scoutdrinks W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

This error does not occur when I am connected to my home WiFi or using cellular data, it only occurs when I am connected to a mobile Hotspot. Anyone knows what is going on and how it can be fixed. My server has a valid LetsEncrypt certificate and my developing device runs on Android 4.0.4 (API 15).

This is my code:

```java
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                url = new URL("my_link");
                conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);

                InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String line = bufferedReader.readLine();


                return line;
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

**EDIT:**
As recommended by someone I made a Wireshark dump containing the traffic between my server and the debugging device. Maybe this will shed some light on the issue?

```
No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      1 0.000000       192.168.43.142        89.40.13.226          TCP      66     27869 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=17520 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 1: 66 bytes on wire (528 bits), 66 bytes captured (528 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: 3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e (3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e), Dst: HuaweiTe_86:6a:66 (b4:86:55:86:6a:66)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.43.142, Dst: 89.40.13.226
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 27869, Dst Port: 443, Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      2 0.086557       89.40.13.226          192.168.43.142        TCP      66     443 → 27869 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1300 SACK_PERM=1 WS=512

Frame 2: 66 bytes on wire (528 bits), 66 bytes captured (528 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: HuaweiTe_86:6a:66 (b4:86:55:86:6a:66), Dst: 3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e (3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 89.40.13.226, Dst: 192.168.43.142
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 443, Dst Port: 27869, Seq: 0, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      3 0.086709       192.168.43.142        89.40.13.226          TCP      54     27869 → 443 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=17408 Len=0

Frame 3: 54 bytes on wire (432 bits), 54 bytes captured (432 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: 3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e (3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e), Dst: HuaweiTe_86:6a:66 (b4:86:55:86:6a:66)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.43.142, Dst: 89.40.13.226
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 27869, Dst Port: 443, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      4 0.094828       192.168.43.142        89.40.13.226          TLSv1.2  571    Client Hello

Frame 4: 571 bytes on wire (4568 bits), 571 bytes captured (4568 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: 3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e (3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e), Dst: HuaweiTe_86:6a:66 (b4:86:55:86:6a:66)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.43.142, Dst: 89.40.13.226
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 27869, Dst Port: 443, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 517
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
        Length: 512
        Handshake Protocol: Client Hello

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      5 0.163546       89.40.13.226          192.168.43.142        TCP      54     443 → 27869 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=518 Win=15872 Len=0

Frame 5: 54 bytes on wire (432 bits), 54 bytes captured (432 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: HuaweiTe_86:6a:66 (b4:86:55:86:6a:66), Dst: 3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e (3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 89.40.13.226, Dst: 192.168.43.142
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 443, Dst Port: 27869, Seq: 1, Ack: 518, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      6 0.164487       89.40.13.226          192.168.43.142        TLSv1.2  1354   Server Hello

Frame 6: 1354 bytes on wire (10832 bits), 1354 bytes captured (10832 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: HuaweiTe_86:6a:66 (b4:86:55:86:6a:66), Dst: 3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e (3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 89.40.13.226, Dst: 192.168.43.142
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 443, Dst Port: 27869, Seq: 1, Ack: 518, Len: 1300
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Server Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 109
        Handshake Protocol: Server Hello

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      7 0.164693       89.40.13.226          192.168.43.142        TCP      1354   443 → 27869 [ACK] Seq=1301 Ack=518 Win=15872 Len=1300 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]

Frame 7: 1354 bytes on wire (10832 bits), 1354 bytes captured (10832 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: HuaweiTe_86:6a:66 (b4:86:55:86:6a:66), Dst: 3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e (3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 89.40.13.226, Dst: 192.168.43.142
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 443, Dst Port: 27869, Seq: 1301, Ack: 518, Len: 1300

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      8 0.164722       192.168.43.142        89.40.13.226          TCP      54     27869 → 443 [ACK] Seq=518 Ack=2601 Win=17408 Len=0

Frame 8: 54 bytes on wire (432 bits), 54 bytes captured (432 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: 3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e (3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e), Dst: HuaweiTe_86:6a:66 (b4:86:55:86:6a:66)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.43.142, Dst: 89.40.13.226
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 27869, Dst Port: 443, Seq: 518, Ack: 2601, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      9 0.165717       89.40.13.226          192.168.43.142        TLSv1.2  487    Certificate, Server Key Exchange, Server Hello Done

Frame 9: 487 bytes on wire (3896 bits), 487 bytes captured (3896 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: HuaweiTe_86:6a:66 (b4:86:55:86:6a:66), Dst: 3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e (3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 89.40.13.226, Dst: 192.168.43.142
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 443, Dst Port: 27869, Seq: 2601, Ack: 518, Len: 433
[3 Reassembled TCP Segments (2572 bytes): #6(1186), #7(1300), #9(86)]
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Certificate
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 2567
        Handshake Protocol: Certificate
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Server Key Exchange
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 333
        Handshake Protocol: Server Key Exchange
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Server Hello Done
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 4
        Handshake Protocol: Server Hello Done

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     10 0.168158       192.168.43.142        89.40.13.226          TLSv1.2  180    Client Key Exchange, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message

Frame 10: 180 bytes on wire (1440 bits), 180 bytes captured (1440 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: 3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e (3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e), Dst: HuaweiTe_86:6a:66 (b4:86:55:86:6a:66)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.43.142, Dst: 89.40.13.226
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 27869, Dst Port: 443, Seq: 518, Ack: 3034, Len: 126
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Key Exchange
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 70
        Handshake Protocol: Client Key Exchange
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Change Cipher Spec Protocol: Change Cipher Spec
        Content Type: Change Cipher Spec (20)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 1
        Change Cipher Spec Message
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Encrypted Handshake Message
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 40
        Handshake Protocol: Encrypted Handshake Message

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     11 0.255375       89.40.13.226          192.168.43.142        TLSv1.2  105    Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message

Frame 11: 105 bytes on wire (840 bits), 105 bytes captured (840 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: HuaweiTe_86:6a:66 (b4:86:55:86:6a:66), Dst: 3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e (3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 89.40.13.226, Dst: 192.168.43.142
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 443, Dst Port: 27869, Seq: 3034, Ack: 644, Len: 51
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Change Cipher Spec Protocol: Change Cipher Spec
        Content Type: Change Cipher Spec (20)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 1
        Change Cipher Spec Message
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Encrypted Handshake Message
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 40
        Handshake Protocol: Encrypted Handshake Message

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     12 0.255951       192.168.43.142        89.40.13.226          TLSv1.2  85     Encrypted Alert

Frame 12: 85 bytes on wire (680 bits), 85 bytes captured (680 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: 3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e (3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e), Dst: HuaweiTe_86:6a:66 (b4:86:55:86:6a:66)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.43.142, Dst: 89.40.13.226
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 27869, Dst Port: 443, Seq: 644, Ack: 3085, Len: 31
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Encrypted Alert
        Content Type: Alert (21)
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Length: 26
        Alert Message: Encrypted Alert

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     13 0.257712       192.168.43.142        89.40.13.226          TCP      54     27869 → 443 [FIN, ACK] Seq=675 Ack=3085 Win=16896 Len=0

Frame 13: 54 bytes on wire (432 bits), 54 bytes captured (432 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: 3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e (3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e), Dst: HuaweiTe_86:6a:66 (b4:86:55:86:6a:66)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.43.142, Dst: 89.40.13.226
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 27869, Dst Port: 443, Seq: 675, Ack: 3085, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     14 0.322180       89.40.13.226          192.168.43.142        TCP      66     [TCP Dup ACK 11#1] 443 → 27869 [ACK] Seq=3085 Ack=644 Win=15872 Len=0 SLE=675 SRE=676

Frame 14: 66 bytes on wire (528 bits), 66 bytes captured (528 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: HuaweiTe_86:6a:66 (b4:86:55:86:6a:66), Dst: 3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e (3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 89.40.13.226, Dst: 192.168.43.142
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 443, Dst Port: 27869, Seq: 3085, Ack: 644, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     15 0.322181       89.40.13.226          192.168.43.142        TCP      54     443 → 27869 [ACK] Seq=3085 Ack=676 Win=15872 Len=0

Frame 15: 54 bytes on wire (432 bits), 54 bytes captured (432 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: HuaweiTe_86:6a:66 (b4:86:55:86:6a:66), Dst: 3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e (3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 89.40.13.226, Dst: 192.168.43.142
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 443, Dst Port: 27869, Seq: 3085, Ack: 676, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     16 0.323105       89.40.13.226          192.168.43.142        TCP      54     443 → 27869 [FIN, ACK] Seq=3085 Ack=676 Win=15872 Len=0

Frame 16: 54 bytes on wire (432 bits), 54 bytes captured (432 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: HuaweiTe_86:6a:66 (b4:86:55:86:6a:66), Dst: 3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e (3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 89.40.13.226, Dst: 192.168.43.142
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 443, Dst Port: 27869, Seq: 3085, Ack: 676, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     17 0.323206       192.168.43.142        89.40.13.226          TCP      54     27869 → 443 [ACK] Seq=676 Ack=3086 Win=16896 Len=0

Frame 17: 54 bytes on wire (432 bits), 54 bytes captured (432 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: 3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e (3a:d3:b8:d8:4f:9e), Dst: HuaweiTe_86:6a:66 (b4:86:55:86:6a:66)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.43.142, Dst: 89.40.13.226
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 27869, Dst Port: 443, Seq: 676, Ack: 3086, Len: 0
```

[Download WireShark File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/143TSTfH4iW2V56QYyhP-GKz5DQSgHk1h/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Maybe this hotspot has a capture portal and requires login or accepting some terms and conditions before one can actually access the internet?

Comment: It does not have such thing, I can browse the internet and access all pages just fine.

Comment: Take a look at this [SSL handshake aborted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741405/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-ssl-handshake-aborted-connection-reset-by-peer-while). It might start you in the right direction.

Comment: The message indicates the peer reset the connection. Assuming you actually reached your server, that means your server sent an RST, and immediately after the TCP connection started. I guess it saw something it didn't like. Are there any logs on the server? How about adding a wireshark/tcpdump to your question?

Comment: I've added a dump to the Original Post. I noticed an "Encrypted Alert" and "Duplicate ACK", maybe this is causing the SSL handshake to fail?

Comment: Not really 100% sure, you may have better luck on the superuser SE. It looks to me like your hotspot may be doing SSL interception. What kind is it? If you go to an `https` website via your hotspot, and you "view the certificate" in your browser, do you get the site's actual certificate, or a cert from the hotspot?

Comment: It would also help if you could verify if 192.168.43.142 is your Android, or your hotspot.

Comment: I can confirm that 192.168.43.142 is the tablet i'm using as debugging device.
Next to that my HotSpot is running on a HuaWei Mate 20 just about a year old. I have noticed though that when my debugging device is connected to the regular WiFi it loads my back-end URL in its browser just fine and says it is a valid certificate, but when connected to the hotspot it gives me an error loading the back-end URL; Connection problem: No secure connection can be initiated. I cannot see the certificate right now. Could it be because my debugging tablet is too old to accept LetsEnc. certs (6 year old)?

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. I can't see how that stack trace could correspond to this .pcap. The .pcap makes it look like the client is getting upset, and terminating the connection (somewhat after it's had a look at the server cert). Now, I don't think the server cert can be the problem, b/c surely the same one is used over WiFi that gets used via the hotspot. And your Java code can't be the problem, b/c the browser is clearly having the same issue. And it also looks like my hunch about SSL interception was completely wrong. I've got nothin'.

Comment: Maybe if you could provide a .pcap of a successful WiFi conversation, that would provide a useful basis for comparison.